# jQuery Multiple ID selector concate through variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
var $btnNone = $('#btn-none');
var $btn1234 = $('#btn-1, #btn-2, #btn-3, #btn-4');

// This selector works fine
var $btnReview1234None = $('#btn-1, #btn-2, #btn-3, #btn-4, #btn-none')

// HOW TO MAKE THIS SELECTOR WORK.
// This selector ignores $btnNone but respects $btn1234.
// This listens only first item in the selector
var $btnReview1234None = $($btn1234, $btnNone); 

$btn1234None.click(function(){
  alert('Lorem')
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `$($btn1234, $btnNone)` will be treated as a contextual selector, ie. jQuery will search the DOM to find the `$btn1234` element *within* `$btnNone`.

To fix this you could provide an array of both elements to the selector:

```
var $btnReview1234None = $([$btn1234, $btnNone]);
```

Or you could use `add()`:

```
var $btnReview1234None = $btn1234.add($btnNone);
```